# Use of variables (bash script) in the mail body in jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I currently have the following script:

var = foo

And the configuration of the email (Editable Email Publisher) I have it like this:
[configuration Email Publisher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXGoE.png)

Reading in other questions, someone said that it worked for him using this:
${ENV, var="var"}

However, it does not work for me, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a script that add environment variable the lifetime of this variable is only until the script ends.
You have plugin Environment Injector (was EnvInject Plugin) that using this plugin you can inject variable to all the job life time.

So if you want to add variable in the build section and to use it in the post build section you need to inject the variable.